# How do I solve these errors? ( Primary key value already exists: 10 . ) and (kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, error-handling, crash

so I have 3 Edit text and three buttons and when ever I write the value of the primary key like this (, count + 2) like down below

```
 realm.beginTransaction()
                        count = realm.where(GoodStudents::class.java).findAll().size
                        val goodStudents =
                            realm.createObject(GoodStudents::class.java, count + 2) // here 
                        //goodStudents.id = count.toLong()
                        goodStudents.name = name.text.toString()
                        try {
                            goodStudents.grade = grade.text.toString().toInt()
                        } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                        }

                        val readData = realm.where(GoodStudents::class.java).findAll()
                        readData.forEach { save ->

                            //                text.text = ""  + save.name + ": " + goodStudents.grade
                            chaptersList.add("" + save.id + ")" + save.name!! + ": " + save.grade)
                        }

                        realm.commitTransaction()

  deleteButton.setOnClickListener {
                    val id  = id1.text.toString().toInt()
                  //  var id = 0
                    val deleteData= realm.where(GoodStudents::class.java).equalTo("id", id).findFirst()
                    realm.beginTransaction()
                    if (id != null) {
                        deleteData!!.deleteFromRealm() // it says that the issue is in this place but I cannot figure this out !! 
                    }
                    else if (id1.text.isEmpty()){
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "ضع رقم من أردت حذفة في خانة - بيانات -", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }

                    realm.commitTransaction()

                    val dataRealmDeleteReader = realm.where(GoodStudents::class.java).findAll()
                    dataRealmDeleteReader.forEach{ read ->

                        chaptersList.add("" + read.id + ")" + read.name!! + ": " + read.grade)
                    }
```

it gives me this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.bluetechnology.realm, PID: 8371
kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    at com.bluetechnology.realm.MainActivity$onCreate$1$onItemSelected$2.onClick(MainActivity.kt:134)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7870)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14952)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7839)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29363)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```

and when I change the value of the primary key to (count + 1)
like in this code:

```
realm.beginTransaction()
                        count = realm.where(GoodStudents::class.java).findAll().size
                        val goodStudents =
                            realm.createObject(GoodStudents::class.java, count + 1) // here is the issue of the second problem 
                        //goodStudents.id = count.toLong()
                        goodStudents.name = name.text.toString()
                        try {
                            goodStudents.grade = grade.text.toString().toInt()
                        } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
                        }

 deleteButton.setOnClickListener {
                    val id  = id1.text.toString().toInt()
                  //  var id = 0
                    val deleteData= realm.where(GoodStudents::class.java).equalTo("id", id).findFirst()
                    realm.beginTransaction()
                    if (id != null) {
                        deleteData!!.deleteFromRealm()
                    }
                    else if (id1.text.isEmpty()){
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "ضع رقم من أردت حذفة في خانة - بيانات -", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
```

it gives me this error

```
io.realm.exceptions.RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException: Primary key value already exists: 9 .
(/Users/cm/Realm/realm-java-release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsObject.cpp:197)
    at io.realm.internal.OsObject.nativeCreateNewObjectWithLongPrimaryKey(Native Method)
    at io.realm.internal.OsObject.createWithPrimaryKey(OsObject.java:208)
    at io.realm.Realm.createObjectInternal(Realm.java:1049)
    at io.realm.Realm.createObject(Realm.java:1024)
    at com.bluetechnology.realm.MainActivity$onCreate$1$onItemSelected$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:108)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7870)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14952)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7839)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29363)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```

P.C.. I've deleted some of the items that I had in my Recycler View

Comment: Thats nt a good way to set primary key value budd. Set the value to auto increment either.

Comment: can you give an example plz??

Comment: Try setting it to count++

Comment: will sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't work also when I delete the id value and write the same id by mistake the app crashes !! I didn't have this issue before

Comment: Delete and write the same..? Means?

Comment: before when i write an id that doesn't exist or it was before I delete it it shows me  a Toast I made that the values are not found but now it crashes when I write in my edit text the id that I want to delete.

Comment: Before it used to show a toast but now crashes on edit text wid your logcat error? If thats the case then u r not deleting the id value correcting on your delete logic.